# Is the output voltage range of the LMT70 analog temperature sensor fixed regardless of Vsupply?

Tags: sensor, temperature

The differential ADC on my circuit has 1 channel open, and I decided that to place a temperature sensor IC. The temperature IC is [LMT70](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmt70.pdf?ts=1606065519970&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). According to the output voltage table from the datasheet, the output voltage in relation to the temperature are:

[image]

My uncertainty comes from that the table shown is for a 2.7V supply, and I can only provide 3.0V (same as the ADC's supply.)

Would this table still hold true even for a 3.0V supply? The ADC uses an internal 1.2V reference and although that 1.2V on this table is -20 degrees Celsius a situation where my circuit will most likely not be exposed to im worried that the 1.2V Vtao of 3.0V supply would creep to the 20 degree Celsius  where the circuit will be exposed to.

Simplified circuit:

[image]

I would hope that I won't have to use a voltage divider to lower the output to not waste the accuracy of the IC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the output voltage changes much with supply voltage variations. For instance, look at this figure for the output voltage at 30 °C versus supply voltage change. I've added vertical lines for supplies of 2.7 volts and 3.3 volts: -

[image]

BTW your schematic is incorrect: -

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the decoupling I made a mistake there.

Comment: Do you think some sort of calibration is needed per board with this IC ? The table gives values in the microvolt (which my adc can theoretically handle) so a slight change in supply voltage might offset the reading. Im already having a hard time thinking of how to get an accurate temperature controlled room to get the readings from >.<

Comment: Though i dont think i need it to be that accurate since this is just a filler component, ill just have to assume that they are the same. Thank you good sir.

Comment: I think if you can get hold of a decent thermocouple sensor then a spot check at a couple of temperatures will be useful as a check.